# How to shutdown my eclipse job after rcp app closes

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, rcp, jobs

I'm using eclipse ui jobs to perform an asynchronous operation. For this when the job is still running and close my rcp app, I get a message on the console saying, !ENTRY org.eclipse.core.jobs 
!MESSAGE Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: com.myPluginame. I'm currently doing this

```
PlatformUI.getWorkbench().addWorkbenchListener(new IWorkbenchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean preShutdown(IWorkbench workbench, boolean forced) {
                        return true;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void postShutdown(IWorkbench workbench) {
                        if (myJob != null) {
                            myJob .cancel();
                        }
                    }
                });
```

after my workbench shuts down, myJob.cancel() code is hit but still, I see the message. Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried moving the cancellation into preShutdown?

Comment: @nitind yes, I moved the code to preShutdown, I get the same message after the workbench shuts down

Comment: Is your Job written to respond to cancellation promptly?

Comment: @nitind I'm calling cancel() on the job, the java doc says, If the job is currently executing, it will be asked to stop but there is no guarantee that it will do so. How do it make my job to respond to cancellation promptly?

Comment: Is this merely an existing Job class you scheduled, or one you actually wrote? If its one you wrote, *you* have to check the IProgressMonitor that was passed in to see if it's been canceled and react accordingly.

Comment: @nitind I actually wrote a job and scheduled it. It seems like I need to override cancelling() method, so when we cancel a Job do we need to cancel the IIProgressMonitor as well??

Comment: No, you ask the progress monitor if it has been canceled (by the user or the system trying to shut down) with #isCanceled, and react accordingly. http://help.eclipse.org/mars/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/core/runtime/IProgressMonitor.html#isCanceled-- http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fruntime_jobs_progress.htm

Comment: @nitind : I dug in to the eclipse code , it seems that we cannot cancel a job that has already been started.

Comment: Its *your* job implementation, isn't it?

Comment: @nitind Yes, it is my job implementation. I understood your previous comment about checking isCanceled on the progress monitor, but my question is what if the shutdown happeens after the call to isCanceled, there is a ui updation that needs to be done after the long job. So, the job should immediately return from whatever it is doing. Thanks on your responses

Comment: Are you using e4? if so try    `@PreSave
   public void preSave() {
      JobManager.shutdown();
   }`

Comment: @titou10 no, I'm not using e4.